Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
When trying to console log a variable I declared inside of my event function, my console is shooting back this error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at HTMLButtonElement.wuTangForever (main.js:16:76)


I tried to make a form, with radio inputs and attributes.
<p>Pepsi or Coke?</p>
<input type="radio" id="pepsi" name="soda" value="1">
<label for="">Pepsi</label>
<input type="radio" id="coke" name="soda" value="2">
<label for="">Coke</label>

In my JavaScript, I have the following code:
const sodas = Number(document.querySelector('input[name = soda]:checked').value)

when I console.log(sodas), or do anything, the message error appears. I checked my script tag as I saw others were having the same issue. That did not resolve the issue.
What I want to do is get the value of the checked radio input, turn that value into a number to put into an array.

querySelector potentially returns null if no matches are found, so your code should handle that case. This looks to be the case if no radio option is selected just yet.
Using the Optional Chaining operator may likely be enough. It checks if the value being chained from is null or undefined and safely accesses the property.
const sodas = Number(
  document.querySelector('input[name = soda]:checked')?.value
);

You may also consider assigning one of the options as a default already selected.
Examples:
<p>Pepsi or Coke?</p>
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="pepsi" name="soda" value="1" checked="true">
  Pepsi
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="coke" name="soda" value="2">
  Coke
</label>

<p>Pepsi or Coke?</p>
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="pepsi" name="soda" value="1" checked>
  Pepsi
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="coke" name="soda" value="2">
  Coke
</label>


Just use "?", so if there's value it will return otherwise you will not get null value error.


const sodas = Number(document.querySelector('input[name = soda]:checked')?.value);
console.log(sodas);




You just copied the code from Drew Reese and added nothing to it that he already provided more than 30 minutes before you.

Same question have same multiple answers, I have just explained in caption that use "?" to avoid null values.

something which has been explained before. A question may have multiple answers with different solutions. In some cases even the same solution as they were written at the same time. But a literally 1 -line answer does not take longer than 30 minutes to explain a coincident with Drew's answer.

Before it I have, answered 1 more question, so I was not allowed to answer with in 30 minutes. I have run this code and posted but due to access i was unable to comment, so I left that time and posted after limit get ends.
